# How to run two independent transaction managers for jpa and jdbc datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I'm developing a standalone application with following technology stack:

- Spring Boot version 2.1.0.RELEASE
- Oracle12c System with driver ojdbc6 (11.2.0.3)
- Apache Camel
- JPA for the main datasource
- JDBC for a secondary datasource (read only)

The JPA datasource is the primary datasource where the application itself is connected to and write data to. The JDBC is an additional datasource to read data from a database with another purpose.

During runtime I encounter the following issue:

I poll/select a JPA Entity from the primary datasource and do some processing. This processing includes running a select query on the secondary datasource via a jdbc template. Now if the execution of the query throws an exception I am able to catch it and want to update a status field on the JPA Entity and write it to the datasource.

I've already read that Oracle tries to do a rollback if a SQLException occurrs. **The issue is that my JPA datasource is unable to commit the changes to the Entity I do when the JDBC query fails.**

It seems to me like the two datasources/transaction managers are not completely independent of each other and that an exception in the secondary datasource causes errors in the primary datasource during commiting changes.

Is this even possible? If yes, how can I configure two independent transaction managers?

EDIT:
I have already tried to annotate the respective methods and classes with @Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class) but this does not solve the problem.

Here are the two Datasource configurations:

**ApplicationDatasourceConfig (JPA)**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "foo.bar.repository.jpa",
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "applicationEntityManagerFactory",
                       transactionManagerRef = "applicationTransactionManager")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationDatasourceConfig extends HikariConfig{

@Bean("applicationDatasource")
@Primary
public DataSource applicationDataSource(){
    return new HikariDataSource(this);
}

@Bean("applicationDatasourceProperties")
@Primary
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties(){
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean("applicationEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean applicationEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                              @Qualifier("applicationDatasource") DataSource dataSource){
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("foo.bar.entity")
            .build();
}

@Bean("applicationTransactionManager")
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager applicationTransactionManager(@Qualifier("applicationEntityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
}
```

**SecondaryDatasourceConfig (JDBC)**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secondary.datasource")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SecondaryDatasourceConfig {

@Bean("secondaryDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource(){
    return secondaryDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
public DataSourceProperties secondaryDataSourceProperties(){
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean("secondaryTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondaryDatasource") DataSource secondaryDataSource){
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(secondaryDataSource);
}
}
```